# Ajax call to a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Background:**

I have one of those scrolling images thing on a website I'm developing. 
The scroller takes in a variable to update the style of a div. (See code below)

**Problem**

I want to change the variable in the style element after 5 seconds.

I understand you need to make an AJAX call to do this. I'm struggling as how to go about it.

**Code:**

```
 <div class="ls-layer" style="<?php echo $SlideLayer1st; ?>">
```

I want to update the `$SlideLayer1st` to `$SlideLayer`

I know JS well, but php is a working progress for me.

Comment: well I believe AJAX is the way to go, if not then any advise is appreciated.

Comment: This is just a simple javascript function. I don't see any AJAX needed unless you don't know the value of `$SlideLayer` when you initially load the page.

Comment: no theres a sperate php file with all the variables on it, I want to toggle the time of the 1st image to be quick then after that revert back to the default time. 

How is this possible in javascript cos I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the ajaxcall. Ajax is only needed when sending clientside info to the server without refreshing.
Just javascript it with a timeout (this will trigger 5s after the document ready):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.ls-layer').removeClass('someClass');
    },5000); // The time is in ms, 5000ms -> 5s
});
```

You can, offcourse, take the `setTimeout()` and place it anywhere. If you want it 5sec after an ajaxcall, place it with the corresponding code.

I've used jQuery in the example above, if you want to change 1 style property, and have an ID (plain JS):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('someId').style.color = 'pink'; // font to pink, example
    // Or, if you want the shole style element removed:
    document.getElementById('someId').removeAttribute("style"); 
},5000); // The time is in ms, 5000ms -> 5s
```

If the removal of the style element is what you are looking for, I suggest you stop thinking about that, and simply make PHP echo a class, and remove the class. If you want to change the style sometime in the future, all you have to do is change the class.
You should **never** have change javascript to change a specific style.

---

If you know what class/style you want the element to load after your phpload:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('element')
        .removeClass('<?php echo 'StartClass';?>')
        .addClass('<?php echo 'FollowUpClass';?>')
},5000); // The time is in ms, 5000ms -> 5s
```

---

And offtopic, the short echo for php might be better to use, these will act the same:

```
<span><?php echo $variable; ?></span>
<span><?= $variable ?></span>
```

Comment: yeah that was my initial thought, but the issue was how to update it so it so it passes a php variable.
it wouldn't be possible for example to say 
`document.getElementById("id").style = $SliderLayer`

Comment: I've editted my post, this should put you on the right track :) You should be able to figure out the details, you can combine some of my examples. Good luck :)

Comment: haha thanks, don't shoot the messenger, I've started this company on a short term basis doing the website and trying to keep with company standards, probably wouldn't have programmed it quite like this. 

So, conclusion is it's not strictly possible the way I'm thinking about it, i'll have to rework stuff. Thanks though

Comment: I just realized that I can't add a class. The class must stay the same otherwise the scroller script will break. It has to be done through the style inline so back to square one!

Comment: You can add more than 1 class to en element? And if your script breaks,make sure you use an unique classname

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this.

```
 $.ajax({
       url: '/some/server/script.php',
       data: { }
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) 
       {
             $('id of div').css('color', newcolor);
      }
 });
```

Comment: Ajax is not needed in this situation, it's only a thought by the TS. Apart from that, there is nothing that will delay 5seconds before performing something :)

Comment: @martijn `<?php sleep(5); ?>` ? :P